# Wordpress query_posts generates weird SQL query for non admin users

Tags: wordpress

I am using query_posts for fetching page 2 of specific author, my query is

```
query_posts(array(
        'author' => $author_id,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    ));
```

For admin it is working fine generating following SQL query :

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND (wp_posts.post_author = 13) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 10, 10"
```

But for any other user not logged in or logged in, SQL query is not executed and returns null generating following query :

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND (wp_posts.post_author = 13) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (( (  (  (  ( 1=2 )  )  )  ) AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' ))  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 20, 10"
```

["posts"]=>

Comment: just because you are passing the author_id so it will not give you the posts. if you need author specific post the use get_posts() method pass the author_id as author parameter.

Comment: @Praveenkalal : Passing an author ID should show posts associated with the specified author, if they exist. I have no idea why you think "it will not give you the posts". Look up the `WP_Query` class.

Comment: I have seen that `1=2` weirdness associated with a bad `meta_query`. I don't know if that is the problem in this case. I would try to find any filters on the query. Disable your plugins... switch to a default theme...

Comment: @s_ha_dum : You are right, its happening because of Role Scoper plugin and user requires capability of 'activate_plugins' then this Query works fine and 1=2 does not appear. But as you can see that right cannot be provide to user its security risk.